# CListCtrl Does CListCtrl display only filled rows?

Tags: c++, mfc, clistctrl

Is the default behaviour for CListCtrl to only show the number of rows that are currently filled with an empty greyed out area beneath?

In my List I have a variable number of entries in a fixed display area. When there are more entries than the display area can hold it is fine, the vertical slider comes up and everything displays correctly. When I delete entries so there are not enough now to fill the display area, the empty area at the bottom becomes greyed out with no cell grid.

I want to keep the display area set out as a complete cell grid. I can calculate and top up that area with empty rows if I have to but I wouldn't have expected this to be the default behaviour. I would have expected the whole Client area of the CListCtrl to stay permanently displayed as an empty cell grid with the correct number of entries displayed at the top.

Do I have to handle this manually or is there perhaps some property of the CListCtrl I am not setting?

Comment: Not sure if I understood everything, could you post some pictures?

Comment: You are asking for very awkward default behavior. What should the default behavior be, if the client area is not a multiple of the cell height? Should the leftover space be grayed out in that case? Should the control show a partial row, without showing an accompanying vertical scrollbar? Should it display a partial row with a vertical scrollbar? How should the scrollbar behave in that case? None of this is very intuitive, and the implemented default behavior really is the route of least surprise.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what I meant.  I am not talking about the partial row which may be left at the bottom, I am talking about all space not currently filled with data.  If I have a CListCtrl which display 40 rows and there are only the top 10 with data, the 30 rows beneath them are just a grey block the same as the dialog background.  I'm not sure how this site handles pics but I've hosted a screenshot on Dropbox to show what I mean:  [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i5rbfpfzhfetpic/ShortList.jpg?dl=0)

Comment: I've got this to work but with clutz code to add empty rows of "", not good if the behaviour should already be that, and you have to handle selection!  You can actually add rows beyond the display, as long as there is no data in the lower cells the VScrollbar will not appear.  So the scrollbar seems based on data rather than display and takes care of your point. What makes me question this is that when the list first displays, before any data has been entered, it shows an empty grid exactly as I want it.  When I populate with data the grey area appears and persists, adjusting with the data.

Answer (score 0):

What you have described *IS* the default behavior of the List View control:

[image: List View control]

Here is the relevant code fragment:

```
m_List.InsertColumn(0, L"Col 1", 0, 100);
m_List.InsertColumn(1, L"Col 2", 0, 100);
m_List.InsertItem(0, L"Item 1");
m_List.InsertItem(1, L"Item 2");
ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle(m_List, LVS_EX_GRIDLINES | LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT);
```

You just need to make sure that you use current version of the Common Controls.

Comment: Thanks for that info Vlad, it is what I was afraid might be the case.  Seems like it's just my ageing setup that is not reliable any more.  I'll have to be careful with this one.